# Braintree client-token validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I am using **braintree Drop-in UI with angularjs(frontend) and rails(Backend)**. I am creating a clientToken and sending it to braintree setup.

The client-token method,

```
@client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id,options: {
            verify_card: true,
            fail_on_duplicate_payment_method: true
            })
```

So as you can see, I have taken '**fail_on_duplicate_payment_method**' option. And trying to add the same payment method again.

Then, with that validation I am getting an error on the dropin saying **"There was an error processing your request", but it is not coming to the error callback.**

This is the setup, which is fine,

```
 braintree.setup(vm.clientToken, 'dropin', {
    container: 'dropin-container',
    onPaymentMethodReceived: function(data) 
    { 
      alert('came recieved')
      // console.log($scope.paymentForm)
      vm.submit($scope.paymentForm, data.nonce)
    },
    onReady: function ()  {
        vm.disablePay = false;
    },
    onError: function(type, message)  {
        alert('came error')
        vm.serverError = message;
    }
});
```

Here is the Image of the error,

[image: Error image]

The error in the network is,

```
callback_jsona7f3c885267b4f49aa13fbf01cecdb60({"error":{"message":"Credit card is invalid"},<br>"fieldErrors":[{"field":"creditCard","fieldErrors":[{"field":"number","code":"81724","message":"Duplicate card exists in the vault"}]}],"status":422})
```

I want to fetch this error into my view. I searched many links, but didn't get the answer I needed. Any help is appreciable.
Thankyou in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full Disclosure: I work as a developer for Braintree</sub>

The `onError` callback is only triggered by client side errors and this is actually a server side error; however, the team is aware of this need and is working on a solution that will be available in a future release.